# Any java framework for metrics monitoring?

Tags: frameworks, notifications, monitor

I have new metrics feeding into db everyday. And I want to monitor it, if the metrics change very large compared to previous day, I want to send out notification, like sending out email ? So is there any java framework to achieve this function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read sometime ago about using Jenkins to run jobs for various metrics related tests. If the job failed, an email was sent automatically from Jenkins.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Eclipse you can use this.
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-metrics#.UIoqvMXMiNA You can just call API and do the stuff you want to do.